# TFHppleElement (Hpple), parsing HTML on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, parsing, hpple

I'm using Hpple and it's been great so far however I want to get all the divs inside another and that I can do. But then I am unable to further parse the contents (innerHTML, and in the source it is labelled innerHTML not innerText) asking for the elements content returns nothing as there is no text directly in that element, only child nodes/elements which then contain text.

What alternatives are there to Hpple and parsing HTML on the iPhone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alternatives to [Hpple](http://github.com/topfunky/hpple/tree/master) I have found so far were:

- [ElementParser](http://github.com/Objective3/ElementParser)
- [Objective-C HTML Parser](http://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)
- [XPathQuery](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html)

Since I am in the process of researching the issue myself I have still no idea, which one is best suited for your problem, however.