# Why is objectForKey:@"" returning (null)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexing, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've been wrestling with this all day and have no idea what i'm doing wrong. I have an `NSDictionary`

```
NSDictionary*dict=[tutorialsNodes objectAtIndex:0];
```

When I `NSLog(@"%@",dict);` it returns the following...

```
{
nodeAttributeArray =     (
            {
        attributeName = class;
        nodeContent = style1;
    }
);
nodeChildArray =     (
            {
        nodeContent = "Number of Patrons Using Facility: 151";
        nodeName = text;
    },
            {
        nodeName = br;
    },
            {
        nodeContent = "
\n      Room Occupancy: 210 ";
        nodeName = text;
    },
            {
        nodeName = br;
    },
            {
        nodeContent = "
\n      Current Wait: 0 minutes ";
        nodeName = text;
    }
);
nodeName = p;
}
```

However, when I enter the following code...

```
NSArray*dictArray=[dict objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"];
NSLog(@"%@",dictArray);
```

It returns `null` . I am trying to pull the nodeContent from the `NodeChildArray` key but I can't even pull the key yet. Not sure why it keeps returning null

REVISION

Here are the exact lines that I am executing...

```
//some HTML parsing before this
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser   
searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

NSDictionary*dict=[tutorialsNodes objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray*dictArray=[dict objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"];

NSLog(@"%@",dictArray);
```

It returns `null` twice

Comment: This output does not look like it was generated from a dictionary object. I suspect it was not serialized properly and is really just a string. Try asking the dictionary for all of its keys with `NSLog(@"%@", [dictArray allKeys]);` to verify that it is serialized properly.

Comment: Verify that `dict` isn't `nil`. If it isn't, then `dict` doesn't have a key of `@"nodeChildArray"`.

Comment: Show us the lines that you're executing, in the precise order that you're executing them, with the NSLog statements included, and with a summary of the relevant declarations.  Most likely you're losing "dict" between the first statement and the second.

Comment: @JoePasq - If the output of the first statement were a string the `objectForKey` on it would fail with "selector not recognized".  My bet is that the first and second statement are not back-to-back, and "dict" never makes it between them.  (The output *does* look like a `description` of an NSDictionary.)

Comment: I just added the code verbatim.

Comment: dict does not return nil, it returns the dictionary I posted in the question. So that means @"nodeChildArray" isn't a key then?

Comment: @pj409: try printing [dict allKeys]

Comment: The app crashed when I print [dict allKeys]...I get the following errror          *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TFHppleElement allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: aha... so there is some problem.... try loging [dict className]

Comment: It won't let me...X code saya 'No Visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'className'

Comment: amazing sometimes it gets TFHppleElement and here agan NSDictinary. what about nslogging `[dict class];`

Comment: There we go...it's a TFHippleElement. Thanks for all your help by the way! much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow convert it into an NSDictionary?

Comment: So, based on the code you posted, you *were not* logging "dict" when you said you were (several times).

Comment: No, I was definitely logging dict, I just tried it again. When I logged [dict class] I got TFHippleElement. But that dictionary-looking code was the output for log dict.

Comment: But the above code does not show that NSLog.  You've never given us the straight story.

Comment: Good call Hot Licks and Anoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment :

> The app crashed when I print [dict allKeys]...I get the following
>   errror *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TFHppleElement allKeys]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instanc

That is why you are not able to extract value based on Key. You are getting THppleElement from the dictionary. You need to again [parse this TFHppleElement to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860941/tfhppleelement-hpple-parsing-html-on-iphone) to get the required valueForKey.